# Is $200 \,\text{J}$ enough for heart defibrillation?

Tags: biology, medical-physics

In some movie I saw that defibrillation was done on a patient by emitting $200 \,\text{J}$ electric impulse onto heart region. I couldn't in noway imagine is this quantity big or small, so I've tried to compare it with gravitational potential energy of person falling from some height.
It appears that such energy person gets falling on the ground from a $20-40\, \text{cm}$ altitude (depends on a person exact weight). So this electroshock energy should be comparable to a *good* hand-punch into a heart zone.

Question 1: Is these $200 \,\text{J}$ is a realistic energy amount for a real life heart reviving scenarios?

Question 2: If answer to (1) is more or less YES, then can electroshock be technically replaced by a simple hand-punch into a heart region in defibrillation procedure? Yes, No and Why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because calculating the appropriate shock to administer for an arrhythmia is in the domain of biology and medicine.

Comment: I want to add although you might think it is technically physics anything in the natural world is governed by physics but it doesn't mean it's a physics question. For example the mechanism of action of an antibiotic is physics in the end - molecules interacting. But that's obviously not the domain of physics as a field.

Comment: Can you suggest other stackexchange site for this question ?

Comment: An average 50 inches LED TV consumes 200 J every 2 seconds. Falling on it, won’t give you 2 seconds of your favorite TV show in the absence of electrical energy. Different kind of energy are **Numerically** equivalent and interchangeable, but not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defibrillators work by delivering electricity to the heart. You make an analogy with mechanical energy. These are not the same.

Your heart includes muscle cells that need to be activated in a specific sequence for the heart to work. To do so, they communicate using electrical currents. If you need defibrillation, this sequence is broken. The purpose of the defibrillator is to provide enough current to reset the system so that the proposer sequence is restored. Note that an external defibrillator needs indeed about 200 Joules to do so, because the current is distributed inside the body: not all of it will flow though the heart. An implanted defibrillator (ie a pacemaker) needs about an order of magnitude less energy.

Delivering mechanical energy to the heart in a punch is a technique that anecdotally sometimes work for defibrillation. It has a very low chance of success and a defibrillator is greatly preferred. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precordial_thump. You basically hope that by compressing the heart enough, you will reset it.

One thing to understand is that defibrillation does NOT work by converting electrical energy to mechanical energy or vice-versa directly in the way we understand it with motors and generators. It works by putting all cardiac cells in a state such that normal heart beating can be restored. Cardiac cells change in potential during contraction by exchanging ions with their environment. By setting all the cells at the same potential, you "reset" the heart. This is of course a bit simplified, but that is the spirit of how these things work.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understood correctly defibrillator induces heart spasm by applying voltage to it. So in principle this effect is similar to Luigi Galvani bioelectricity experiment, because in theory all muscles should contract / react to applied current, isn't it ?

Comment: This is the general spirit, although you have to distinguish "stimulating or simulating a nerve that will in turn stimulate a muscle", as in the galvanic experiment, and "stimulating the muscle directly", as in defibrillation. A detailed explanation would be long and outside of the scope of this site.If you want to learn more, look into electrophysiology on Google, or any human physiology textbook.